# Concurrent Connections to wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Currently we are using wso2 4.1.0 version. we are using soap based services authentication admin, entitlements service for getting policy decision ,  getting claims values. we are using cxf for our webservice clients. when we make calls with 500 concurrent users from a single machine everything works fine. but when we make it to 1000 concurrent users we are seeing a huge response time for these service calls from wso2 is. can you tell if there is any configuration change that we need to make for tuning. we increased the wso2 is axis client no. of connections per host but we still didn't see any improvement. By the way we are using the default configuration of wso2 is out of the box

Thanks
Kishore

Answer (score 1):

There are some places you can improve the performances.

1.Increase the memory setting. you can find it in the wso2server script file in /bin. can u increase default value and see..  such as

-Xms1024m  -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

2.Increase max thread pool size in catalina-server.xml file  which can find in /repository/conf/tomcat

maxThreads="250"

3.Increase caching timeout value.  entitlement.properties file which can find in /repository/conf/security

4.Please check you are not authenticating for each request. You need to call AuthenticationAdmin 1st time and get the cookie and then use cookie for subsequence requests.

Else could do use some Jconsole or Jprofiler and see what is going wrong?   Also according to your environment,  this can be the max load that one server can handle, then you need to do horizontal  scaling. (adding WSO2 Identity Server more instance in a cluster)

Comment: We have experienced the same problem. We've also tried with different memory settings/cache configuration. Would be nice if you could share what config hardware/setting would allow what number of (concurrent) users.